# Cut a disk from a torus?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

I am learning the quotient topology.

I want to make connected sum of two torus. So, for this I am using the planar model of torus.

[image]

In the above fig the black part is a disk that I have cut.

I want to know in the planer model why we cut a disk like this? What is the process?

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Just glue the planer model and see what it is. What part is vague for you?

Comment: @C.F.G I know the gluing. Also I can get an octagon. I want to know how we cut a disk from the planar model. What is the yellow part of the planner model? Why the disk in the planar model look like the yellow part?

Comment: In topology we don't care about shape. e.g. a circle and a simple loop are one (they are homeomorphic and that's it). here the yellow part is homeo to a usual disk. isn't?